# Nuget Package Restore not working-

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, square-connect

I am trying to run the example C# code in visual studio for square connect:

https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment

When I open the solution all of the references have a yellow triangle with and exclamation point next to them.

I have tried to restore nuget packages on the solution, uninstall and reinstall some and i can't get the triangles to go away.  It won't build for me.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You need to post the relevant code, nobody wants to go through your whole repo to decypher what your issue is. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a target in their project file that [can become problematic](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3320) when projects are moved between systems.

You can fix the problem with two steps:

1. Remove the entire `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" ..>` element at the end of the project file, then reload the project.
2. Execute an `Update-Package -Reinstall` in your (NuGet) Package Manager Console.

That should set everything right for your system and re-point to the correct versions of the relevant libraries.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete packages folder at solution root and rebuild or restore packages again.